# Уроки для тренировки верстки

Tags: вёрстка

Подскажите какие нибудь тренировочные задания для набивания и заучивания верстки сначала от простого к сложному, хтмл и css. Потом php и javaskript. Что то типа лабораторных работ...

Comment: Вот Вам первое тренировочное задание - напишите правильно слово JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Придумывать конкретные задания, вам тут вряд ли будут. Но вы и сами можете себе составлять такие задачи. Если умеете не плохо рисовать, то создайте себе эскиз странички и попробуйте "воплотить его в жизнь". Но для новичка, на мой взгляд, будет отличной тренировкой в этом направлении - создание "клона" какого-то существующего сайта. Заходите, к примеру, на такой ресурс, как [awwwards.com](http://www.awwwards.com/), выбираете какой-нибудь сайтик и **не заглядывая в исходные коды**, пытаетесь воспроизвести его самостоятельно. Вот, к примеру, [страничка сайта](http://www.whatsmynvme.com/), где даже эффекты реализованы на CSS3.  Укрепите познания в HTML и CSS, переключайтесь на добавления всяких "плюшек" на страницу с использованием JS.